# Words move from line to line as you change paragraph alignment

Tags: microsoft-word

I noticed a strange behavior in Word, words move from line to line when changing the alignment of the paragraph, if the alignment to two sides it looks like this:

[image: two sides]

And if the alignment to the left it looks like that

[image: left]

You can see that a word went from line to line.
This only happens in Word 2013 and above, but not in Word 2010.

My question is there a way that this will not happen so that the words will always remain in the same line in alignment to both sides and also in alignment to the left?

Comment: While it's indeed strange, I can't see what practical issue this would cause. Text is generally formatted left aligned OR justified, but NOT BOTH. When people read the document they don't know how that would look like with different formatting.

Comment: "is there a way that this will not happen so that the words will always remain in the same line in alignment to both sides and also in alignment to the left?" I don't see how that would be possible, as they're different alignments so should be expected to be different. Left align lines everything up to the left, and justification distributes text across lines. Part of distributing text across lines is moving text that doesn't fit well. It's what it does.

Comment: Hey! as a workaround, you can change the page margins a little.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Word changes the size of spaces when displaying justified text. That's *how* it justifies the text. You can stretch a white space more than a letter before a reader notices. Spaces may get larger or smaller, depending on need.

Watch the spacing between words as I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> to quickly alternate between left-aligned and justified text.

[image: Gif]

The change is small but, in this case, it was enough to change the wrap position.

---

Asking how to make this not happen is asking how to justify text without justifying text.

Answer (score 1):

As user Engineer Toast has said, by specifying justified text you have given Word
permission to arrange inter-word spacing as it likes, larger or smaller.

It seems like the word "occaecat" missed being included into the line by only
a few pixels, so that a minuscule reduction of some inter-word spacings in
the line was enough for getting it to fit in, which is an optimization that
Word knows how to do.

However, when you specify Left alignment, you don't give Word the permission
for varying inter-word spacing, specifying instead the fixed spacing that is
defined for the paragraph style. The word in this case no longer fits into
the line and is moved to the next line.

---

Working around this feature of Word is not simple.

One try would be to change the
[Font character spacing](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/font-advanced-settings-b5b42f97-eda9-406a-b1f1-295cf2954c3d?ns=winword&version=19&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=zwd190&helpid=244&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)
of the paragraph, although this might be too strong a change.

Otherwise, you could manually choose one or more blank space
character(s) in this line and reduce their font size to make them smaller.
You only need to make a very tiny difference to avoid the problem for this
paragraph, and this shouldn't affect the display in Justified mode.

Comment: Thank you, but it's not a solution, it's an explanation for Ward's behavior, but I'm still in trouble because of this behavior and I have no solution.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, sometimes when you change left and right alignment, the layout of the document does change, and some text or punctuation appears on the next line.

To avoid this, you can choose to change the spacing of the text, reduce text spacing usually helps.

Select the text that you want to change.

On the Home tab, click the Font Dialog Box Launcher, and then click the Advanced tab.

In the Spacing box, click Expanded or Condensed, and then specify how much space you want in the By box.

More information:

[Change the spaces between text](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-spaces-between-text-e9b96011-1c42-45c0-ad8f-e8a6e4a33462#:%7E:text=Expand%20or%20condense%20the%20space,then%20click%20the%20Advanced%20tab.&text=In%20the%20Spacing%20box%2C%20click,want%20in%20the%20By%20box.)

Comment: Thank you, but this solution may solve one problem but cause another problem that my text must be Expanded or Condensed to at least 0.1, which is a problem for me.